# How can I redirect page without changing URL with PHP?

Tags: php, url, nginx

I want the following:

After logging in, A user will have assigned session variable, and the logging in page will be refreshed. The URL should not be changed at all but the page would be different.

I don't know the idea of doing that.

I know that Facebook does it. (Logging in, and logged in page url is same but different page)

I'm using nginx, PHP.

Should I some sort of rewrite URL? or some configuration on nginx? Or should I manipulate header with php in some way? then how to?

Comment: The usual way is to decide within PHP what to show: The login form, or the contents. No special tricks are necessary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just do a conditional on an include. In general if the session does not exist you say something like

```
<?
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])){ include_once("login_please.php"); exit(); }

..actual page content

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP to decide what to show (or which page to include) based on the session variable.

```
if ($_SESSION['form_submitted'] == true) {
    include('content.php');
}
else include('form.php');
```